# Vuejs sorting not working when filter is active

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am new to Laravel, and Vue and want to create a site for our Intranet.
I got my data from the Laravel database. Listing the data works fine, also the search works fine.
Sorting the data in the table works fine when the search value is empty.
As soon as I enter a value and want to sort the result of the search is not sorted.
I can see in the dev tools that the sort direction, sort column, and sort icon are changed, but nothing happens.

The index.vue Script setup:

```
const props = defineProps({
    locations: Array,
});

const Filters = ref(true)
const Export = ref(false)
const sortColumn = ref('id')
const sortDirection = ref(false)
const arrowIconName = ref('fa-solid fa-arrow-up')
const searchFilter = ref('')
const showFilter = ref(false)
const itemsFilter = ref([])
// Table Pagination
const itemsPerPage = ref(15)

/* Table Labels and Data */
const columns = ref([
        { 
            label: 'Nr.', 
            key: 'id',
            sortable: true,
            type: 'number',
            visible: true,
            filter: false,
        },
        { 
            label: 'Bezeichnung', 
            key: 'bezeichnung',
            sortable: true,
            type: 'text',
            visible: true,
            filter: true,
        },
        { 
            label: 'Straße', 
            key: 'strasse',
            sortable: true,
            type: 'text',
            visible: true,
            filter:true,
        },
        { 
            label: 'HausNr.', 
            key: 'hausnummer',
            sortable: false,
            type: 'text',
            visible: true,
            filter:false,
        },
        {
            label: 'Plz',
            key: 'plz',
            sortable: false,
            type: 'number',
            visible: true,
            filter: false,
        },
        {
            label: 'Ort',
            key: 'ort',
            sortable: false,
            type: 'text',
            visible: true,
            filter: false,
        }
    ]
);

// Searchbar Filter
const filteredItems = computed(() => {
    
    if(searchFilter.value != '') {
        return props.locations.filter(location => {
            return searchFilter.value
                .split(', ')
                .every(v => 
                    location.bezeichnung.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) ||
                    location.strasse.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) ||
                    location.ort.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) ||
                    location.hausnummer.toString().includes(v) ||
                    location.plz.toString().includes(v)
                )
        })
    }
    return props.locations
})

// Sort Column
const handleSort = (col) => {
    sortColumn.value = col
    sortDirection.value = !sortDirection.value
    
    if(sortDirection.value == false) {
        arrowIconName.value = 'fa-solid fa-arrow-up'
        return filteredItems.value.sort((a, b) => (a[col] > b[col] ? 1: -1))
    } else {
        arrowIconName.value = 'fa-solid fa-arrow-down'
        return filteredItems.value.sort((a, b) => (a[col] < b[col] ? 1: -1))
    }
}
```

The table component loaded the data:

```
<div class="overflow-x-auto grow pl-6 pr-6">
    <DataTable 
        :items="filteredItems" 
        :itemsPerPage="itemsPerPage"
        :columns="columns" 
        :color="user.color" 
        :editRoute="'/location-edit/'" 
        :deleteRoute="'/location-destroy/'" 
        @col="handleSort" 
        :sortColumn="sortColumn" 
        :sortDirection="sortDirection" 
        :arrowIconName="arrowIconName"
     />
</div>
```

I tried to find out where my mistake is with the Vue dev tools and console logging in my handleSort.
Everything works fine, but the handleSort does not return filteredItems when the searchFilter is not empty.

Comment: I don't see change searchFilter in your code. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem, not chunks of code!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work.
I put the sort logic into the filteredItems.
Now its working.

```
const filteredItems = computed(() => {

let tempItems = props.locations

if(searchFilter.value != '') {
    tempItems = tempItems.filter(location => {
        return searchFilter.value
            .split(', ')
            .every(v => 
                location.bezeichnung.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) ||
                location.strasse.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) ||
                location.ort.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase()) ||
                location.hausnummer.toString().includes(v) ||
                location.plz.toString().includes(v)
            )
    })
}

if(sortDirection.value == false) {
    console.log(sortColumn.value)
    arrowIconName.value = 'fa-solid fa-arrow-up'
    tempItems = tempItems.sort((a, b) => (a[sortColumn.value] > b[sortColumn.value] ? 1: -1))
} else {
    arrowIconName.value = 'fa-solid fa-arrow-down'
    tempItems = tempItems.sort((a, b) => (a[sortColumn.value] < b[sortColumn.value] ? 1: -1))
}

return tempItems
```

})